# What is the best way to have multiple variations of a product in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a project that I maintain for a client; let's call it MyDataAssistant. When the project goes into beta, the client likes to have a "separate app" built for them, which I create using a different provisioning profile and a modified bundle identifier (MyDataAssistant-BETA). It's a pain to always be going back and forth and changing the bundle identifier, code signature settings, and especially the icon. I understand that you can have multiple targets and multiple build settings (within each target?) in a project, but I'm not clear on what the difference is, or how to use them appropriately.

Additionally, the client would like a third version with read-only capabilities. I can accomplish this by just making a flag return from a certain part of my code, but I would like it if that flag could be toggled in the build (target?) settings.

Please advise on how to manage this kind of project with multiple "variations" of the build.

Comment: USe multiple targets for your project. Each target should have its own Info.plist with its own unique bundle identifier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a new configuration to your project by duplicating the release one for example.

[image]

Give it a name "Beta"

[image]

Add a User-defined build setting

[image]

Call it `MY_DATA_ASSISTANT_BUNDLE_ID_SUFFIX` for example and set the value to be `-BETA` only for the Beta configuration.

[image]

Edit the `MyDataAssistant-info.plist` file by setting the bundle identifier to `com.YOURCOMPANYNAME.MyDataAssistant$(MY_DATA_ASSISTANT_BUNDLE_ID_SUFFIX)`

This will make it have different values for the different configurations.

You can also set the display name to have a different value by setting it to `$(PRODUCT_NAME)$(MY_DATA_ASSISTANT_BUNDLE_ID_SUFFIX)`

[image]

Set the right provisioning profile for each configuration. (Of course after creating the beta one in the provisioning portal as if it was for a new app with the bundle identifier having the suffix "-BETA")

[image]

Create a new scheme!

[image]

Give it a name: MyDataAssistant-BETA

[image]

Change its build configuration to "Beta" for all the actions and you should be ready to go.
[image]

If you want to have different icons for the beta version you can use the `$(MY_DATA_ASSISTANT_BUNDLE_ID_SUFFIX)` in the `MyDataAssistant-info.plist` file for the icons names and of course add them to the target.

Comment: Nice screenshots, but you would recommend to configurations over two targets? What if another file has to be different between builds.

Comment: @JustinMeiners If there is a need to have different files then I wouldn't recommend it. But for a beta version and being able to have the app from the app store and the one in development, it's perfect. On can even use user defined build settings by adding them to info.plist file in order to have different behaviour for different builds (For instance pre-production/production servers url can be built based on that). The advantage over having two targets is that you set it once (well) and you're sure the released configuration version is the same. No worries for missing files for example...

Comment: Agreed I think your method is better as long as you are positive that no other files need to be different between versions.

Comment: It's a little bit more work the first time you set it but then you don't have to think about it at all. Of course there are cases where another target is a better option.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome detail. I had come close to figuring this out before, but couldn't quite figure it out. Creating the user-defined setting was just what I needed to pull everything together. As stated, this might not work if you have different files in some variations, but in my case, it's strictly for the purpose of having separate BundleIDs and disabling certain features, so your solution is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend creating two targets. This will allow you to share what files you want between variations, as well as have custom source, or config files in each. The simplest implementation of this would be to have an identical target except for the info.plist file.

Simply right click on your current app target in project settings, and hit duplicate.